# Need help converting a Multi-Cell Excel formula to basic pseudo code

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula, pseudocode, array-formulas

I don't think the whole spreadsheet is relevant here (Hope I am not wrong) but essentially I am working with some financial figures and need to work out a "Cumulative Cost".
The spreadsheet is correct, but I don't understand the maths of the formula, so I hope somebody can break it down into BODMAS or pseudo code or something (or even Java which it will ultimately be.)

```
{=(PRODUCT($D$4:D7/100+1)-1)*100}

{=(PRODUCT($D$4:D8/100+1)-1)*100}

{=(PRODUCT($D$4:D9/100+1)-1)*100}
```

etc..

I think I only needed to supply one formula, but just giving a few more for context.

So the formulas above are found in column E: 
[Screenshot of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMYkS.png)

Thanks!

Comment: If it will ultimately be in Java, why did you tag with `javascript`?

Comment: I was just looking for an answer in that sort of syntax style. I guess I was thinking about who might be answering it when I tagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the formula, `/100+1`, converts from a percentage change. The part, `-1)*100`, converts to a percentage change. `PRODUCT()` multiplies the numbers togther.

```
double d[12], e[12]; // input and output arrays, respectively
double p = 1.0; // to accumulate the product

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    p = p * ((d[i] / 100) + 1);  // convert from percentage and multiply
    e[i] = (p - 1) * 100;        // convert to percentage
}
```

Additional `(` and `)` and spaces added for clarity.