# Evaluation expression:- Python vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm replicating an equation in javascript in python.

Here's the equation in Javascript:-

```
var q = 1;
var c = [608875978, 500902236, -1359500678, -1631660920];
var x = c[q >>> 2] >>> 24 - q % 4 * 8 & 255;
```

Output `:- x = 74`

Similar in Python:-

```
def rshift(val, n):
    return (val % 0x100000000) >> n

i = 1
words = [608875978, 500902236, -1359500678, -1631660920]
x = rshift((words[rshift(i, 2)]), 24) - i % 4 * 8 & 255
print(x)
```

Output `:- x = 28`

I'm sure `rshift` is returning the right value. What exactly is wrong with Python evaluation vs JS evaluation?

Comment: Put brackets in the evaluation order you want. That applies to both equations because it's super hard to say which is processed in which order.

Comment: The JavaScript code gives 28.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, actually I just tried it but you beat me to commenting.

Comment: Okay. No, wait. I did some mistake. Updating my question.

Comment: Also "bodmas" is not in very common use, at least with respect to JavaScript expression syntax. I'm pretty sure this is the first time in 10 years I've seen it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Pointy for some weird coincidence, that's the *second* time I saw it. The first was  [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958162/need-help-converting-a-multi-cell-excel-formula-to-basic-pseudo-code).

Comment: I've updated the question. My bad for thinking the otherwise.

Comment: OK, be aware that JS uses only 32-bit numbers when doing bitwise arithmetic. Any number outside that range would be forcefully converted, so it's entirely possible that Python calculates it *correctly* because it doesn't do the 32bit conversion

Comment: The JavaScript expression is evaluated as `(c[q >>> 2] >>> (24 - ((q % 4) * 8))) & 255` as can be determined from the [operator precedence rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. This worked.

Comment: Also, can someone please help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962418/chrome-dev-tool-csm-hit-cookie-in-amazon

It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the same in python and it outputs `74`:

```
q = 1;
c = [608875978, 500902236, -1359500678, -1631660920];
x = c[q >> 2] >> 24 - q % 4 * 8 & 255;
print(x) // prints `74`
```

Note: In python, I just replaced `>>>` with `>>`.

I'm not python expert - I just started learning from yesterday. So, I can't analyze your example code now. But you should fix - there might be some issue.

---

As far as I know, any language follow the same math rule.